# Caitlyn's Passive and Runaan's hurricane, how is it affected?

Tags: league-of-legends

So I'm a bit confused by things going around about how Runaan's Hurricane interacts with caitlyn's passive. I understand that the other attacks from runaan's add stacks but if you're in the brush are the shots from the smaller bolts also doubled thus making a total of 6 stacks if you're in the bush and attacking three targets? So far I have only found assumptions on the internet. Anyone have a good link or tested this out themselves?

Comment: I would say it does because Caitlyn's passive adds a Headshot Stack  and an extra stack if in a bush. Considering Runaan's Hurricane applied on-hit effects they'd also need to be affected by her passive. Then again, only the *primary* shot fired from her autos can trigger the bonus damage, this would make me sceptical.

Comment: Related: [Is Runaan's Hurricane worth it on Kennen or Caitlyn?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/120580/is-runaans-hurricane-worth-it-on-kennen-or-caitlyn)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are some basic things to know about Caitlyn's passive. Each time you basic attack, Caitlyn stacks a passive. Once this passive reaches 5 stacks, your next basic attack will give you the Headshot buff, which gives your next basic attack bonus damage.

Therefore, Caitlyn's passive has 6 states: uncharged, 1-4 stacks, and charged.

Here are some trials I ran without Runaan's Hurricane:

```
From bush: Uncharged -> 2 stacks
Not from bush: Uncharged -> 1 stack
From bush: 4 stacks -> Uncharged (used up passive)
Not from bush: 4 stacks -> Charged
```

And here are the trials with Runaan's Hurricane:

```
From bush: 2 stacks -> Charged (hit 3)
Not from bush: 2 stacks -> Charged (hit 3)

From bush: Charged -> 4 (hit 3, used passive)
Not from bush: Charged -> 2 (hit 3, used passive)
```

With this data, we can derive two salient points.

1. Runaan's Hurricane will give 2 stacks for Caitlyn's passive if she is in the bush.
2. Caitlyn's passive will not increase damage for nor be consumed by Runaan's Hurricane's procs.

Note: If Runaan's Hurricane hits before Caitlyn's basic attack and stacks up her passive for her, then Caitlyn's basic attack will consume the Headshot buff and deal bonus damage.